# Print dictionary in objective c

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, for-in-loop

i can't print my array, and i don't understand what is my problem

in class Bank i have

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *accounts;
```

and  VOID function for create account in bank:

```
-(void)createAccount{
    int x=random()%10;
    NSString *keys=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",x];
    Account *new_account=[[Account alloc]initWithAccountNum:x];
    [self.accounts setObject:new_account forKey:keys];
}
```

in class Account i have

```
@property int num;
@property int plus;
```

and methods:

```
-(id)initWithAccountNum:(int)_num{
    self=[self init];
    if(self!=nil){
        self.num=_num;
        self.plus=0;
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString*)printer{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Account num=%i plus=%i",self.num,self.plus];
 }
```

i try print data to Nslog i main file:

```
Bank *bank=[[Bank alloc]init];
[bank createAccount];

for (Account *acc in bank.accounts) {
    Account *printed_account=[bank.accounts objectForKey:acc];
    NSLog(@"%@",printed_account.printer);

}
```

Comment: Do you initialize self.accounts in the init of Bank or is it nil?

Comment: Replace the for content with just `NSLog(@"%@",acc)`. Replace the -printer method signature with `-(NSString*) description`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bank.accounts` should be allocated and initialised before you attempt to use it.

```
self.accounts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

---

Addendum:

To affect what is printed out by `NSLog` for an object you can override `description`

So your `Account` should probably read:

```
-(NSString*)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Account num=%i plus=%i",self.num,self.plus];
}
```

---

`NSMutableDictionary` already has quite a good description of the format:

```
2013-01-04 12:03:11.405 AppName[19683:c07] {
    key1 = value1;
    key2 = value2;
}
```

so you can simplify your loop to: `NSLog(@"%@", bank.accounts);`

Comment: i'm not have anything in output
i change function "createAccount" to Nsstring and in main NSlog I see the new account

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", bank.accounts);` will print out, at the very least `(null)`, if you're not even getting to that statement.

Comment: Then you need to initialise `accounts` in `Bank init`. `self.accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`

Comment: sorry, and thanks for all. i'm new in objective c. i forget do this:
self.accounts=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

Comment: No need to thank. Accept answers that are right by clicking the little ✓ next to the answer and optionally upvote them